# System.StackOverflowException WPF MVVM

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I am trying to create a simple digital clock in WPF using MVVM. I have a label which has a binding. The code behind is simple simple and raising a property changed event each second and I have a stackoverflow exception. Can someone please help ?

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window, INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.DataContext = this;
    }
    private string _lblValue;
    public string LabelValue
    {
        get
        {
            UpdateLabel();
            return _lblValue;
        }
        set
        {
            _lblValue = value;
            OnPropertyChanged(LabelValue);
        }
    }

    private void UpdateLabel()
    {
        _lblValue = System.DateTime.Now.ToString();
        //System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(2000);
        OnPropertyChanged("LabelValue");
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    protected void OnPropertyChanged(string propName)
    {
        var handler = PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null)
        {
            handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propName));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: As a side notenode, what you are doing is a violation of MVVM pattern. Window is a View class, tightly coupled to WPF framework. Your ViewModels can't depend on `Window`, `Component` or other UI classes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As har07 explained it is a infinite UI loop. Here is my fix for this issue.

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window, INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.DataContext = this;

        Task.Run(() => UpdateLabel());
    }

    private string _lblValue;
    public string LabelValue
    {
        get
        {
            return _lblValue;
        }
        set
        {
            _lblValue = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    private void UpdateLabel()
    {
        while (true)
        {
            LabelValue = System.DateTime.Now.ToString();
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    protected void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propName = null)
    {
        var handler = PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null)
        {
            handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propName));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Stephen. This worked.. I was trying to come up with a simple example of binding and raising an event. I was stuck at that point. Appreciate your response.

Answer (score 2):

This is what happens :

1. `UpdateLabel()` function invoked in the getter of `LabelValue`
2. `UpdateLabel()` call `OnPropertyChanged("LabelValue");`
3. Step 2 causes UI to check for updated value of property `LabelValue`,
   in other words it causes getter of `LabelValue` called
4. Back to step 1.

All of above steps repeated until stackoverflow exception thrown. Try to remove step 2 to fix the problem.

Answer (score 0):

In your case it would be better to use a timer with an interval of one second.
For Example:

using System.Timers;

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window, INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private Timer _clockTimer;

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.DataContext = this;

       _clockTimer = new Timer(1000); // The interval is in milliseconds
       _clockTimer.Elapsed += (sender, e) =>
       {
           LabelValue = System.DateTime.Now.ToString();
       };
    }

    private string _lblValue;
    public string LabelValue
    {
        get
        {
            return _lblValue;
        }
        set
        {
            _lblValue = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("LabelValue");
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    protected void OnPropertyChanged(string propName)
    {
        var handler = PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null)
        {
            handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propName));
        }
    }
}
```

If you have further question on Timers, you can look on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Timers.Timer.aspx) for more information.