# Different behavior when Binding TimePicker and CalendarDatePicker UWP

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp, windows-10, windows-10-universal

This question is more of a curiosity, as I have already found a workaround, but I would still like to understand the difference. I have a simple ContentDialog derived class which allows to select two dates and times, using CalendarDatePicker and TimePicker respectively. I have bound their Date and Time properties as follows:

```
        <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0">
            <TextBlock>From</TextBlock>
            <CalendarDatePicker  Date="{x:Bind DateFromDate, Mode=TwoWay}" />
            <TimePicker Time="{x:Bind DateFromTime, Mode=TwoWay}" />
        </StackPanel>

        <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0">
            <TextBlock>To</TextBlock>
            <CalendarDatePicker  Date="{x:Bind DateToDate, Mode=TwoWay}" />
            <TimePicker Time="{x:Bind DateToTime, Mode=TwoWay}" />
        </StackPanel>
```

with the following Code Behind:

```
    private DateTimeOffset _dateFromDate;
    private TimeSpan _dateFromTime;
    private DateTimeOffset _dateToDate;
    private TimeSpan _dateToTime;


    private DateTimeOffset DateFromDate
    {
        get => _dateFromDate;
        set
        {
            _dateFromDate = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged();
        }
    }
    private TimeSpan DateFromTime
    {
        get => _dateFromTime;
        set
        {
            if (value != _dateFromTime)
            {
                _dateFromTime = value;
                NotifyPropertyChanged();
            }    
        }
    }

    private DateTimeOffset DateToDate
    {
        get => _dateToDate;
        set
        {
            _dateToDate = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged();
        }
    }
    private TimeSpan DateToTime {
        get => _dateToTime;
        set
        {
            if(value != _dateToTime)
            {
                _dateToTime = value;
                NotifyPropertyChanged();
            }
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged = delegate { };

    private void NotifyPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = "") =>  PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
```

You might notice that in the TimeSpan properties bound to the TimePickers, there is a check whether the property was changed. If I remove this, and leave it as in the DateTimeOffset properties, a StackOverflowException is raised every time I set those properties. If you google for that, you will reach questions such as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22549104/system-stackoverflowexception-wpf-mvvm), where a quite obvious infinite recursion is occurring. If I debug it, the setter gets indeed called again and again, so my theory is that somewhere in the Code Behind of TimePicker, when it receives the Notification, it not only gets the property, but also sets it. Any ideas?

Comment: No, when I bind TimePicker with a TimeSpan property (as you can see there), but I don't do the `if (value != _dateFromTime)` check when setting the property.

Comment: Could you mind share complete code that could reproduce this issue ?

Comment: Ok, I got it, I could reproduce your issue.

Answer (score 1):

> here a quite obvious infinite recursion is occurring. If I debug it, the setter gets indeed called again and again

I could reproduce this issue, it looks x:Bind TwoWay model make the binding circular, I can sure it is not by design. Currently there are many workarounds for solving this.

**Use Binding to replace x:Bind.**

```
public TimeSpan DateToTime
{
    get => _dateToTime;

    set
    {

        _dateToTime = value;
        OnPropertyChanged();

    }
}
       
<TimePicker Time="{Binding DateToTime, Mode=TwoWay}" />
```

**Modify TwoWay to OneWay.**

```
<TimePicker Time="{x:Bind DateFromTime, Mode=OneWay}" />
```

And the latest one is your mentioned  that use condition statement to stop this loop.

Please feel free report this with windows feed back hub app. And I will keep going to track this problem.

**Update**

Please note that the documentation for NotifyPropertyChanged clearly states to only trigger the NotifyPropertyChanged event when the value actually changes.
Note that the behavior is undefined when not following the documentation. Therefore when the documentation isn’t followed, you cannot make assumptions that the behavior in the bad scenarios will be consistent since both behaviors are undefined.

Here’s the [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/winforms/how-to-implement-the-inotifypropertychanged-interface) on `INotifyPropertyChanged`.

The issue only reproduces when the property’s setter does not guard against triggerting PropertyChanged when the value is equal to previous value. Therefore, regardless of difference in behavior, they’re both undefined behavior. If you don’t follow the documentation, you should expect things to break in weird ways, again because the behavior is undefined.

> why DatePicker could work without value is equal to previous value?

An undefined behavior might happen to line up with expectations in some scenario, but given it’s not following documentation, it would be risky since it could change at any point in time with no warning.

Comment: Thanks for looking into it. I agree this must be a bug, it is of course more likely so, if Binding does it correctly and x:Bind does not.